# Powershell regex to remove everything except key

Tags: regex, powershell

Given a string like

'The fingerprint is: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678910111'

How would you remove all text that isn't a 40 character string consisting of A-Z 0-9 ?

Currently I'm looking for the string 'The fingerprint is: ' and removing it, but I feel it would be safer to look for a 40 character alphanumeric.

```
$foo = $foo -replace 'The fingerprint is: ',''
```

I expect something like this to work, but no luck.

```
$foo = $foo -creplace '^[A-Z0-9]{40}',''
```

I've also tried just looking for the characters that match

```
$foo = $foo -match '[A-Z0-9]{40}'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends a bit, but if it's 40 contiguous and it's the only 40 character string you could use replace:

```
"The fingerprint is: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678910111" -replace '.*([A-Z0-9]{40}).*', '$1'
```

Note: The replacement, $1, is a reference to the match group. It is not a PowerShell variable and is deliberately written in single quotes so it will not expand.

Comment: If it's the *only* 40 character string, skip the regexes and `"The fingerprint is: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678910111".split() |? Length -eq 40`

Answer (score 2):

To match the 40 character alphanumeric with no replacement, this

```
$foo = 'The fingerprint is: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678910111';
$foo -Match '[A-Z0-9]{40}' | Out-Null;
Write-Output $matches[0];
```

prints

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678910111
```

- `[A-Z0-9]` is a bracket expression matching any of the contained characters (`-` denotes a range of values)
- `{40}` matches the previous element 40 times
- `Out-Null` suppresses the boolean return value of the `-match` operator

Comment: Lovely succinct example, but do be mindful that \w also matches underscore (_).

Comment: @ChrisDent Good to know about [\w](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx), thanks!